# Ruby/Rails creating a dynamic method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a fairly large ruby codebase and I am trying to find a method, `current_user_has_ownership?`.  When I grep the codebase it is used in multiple places, but there is no definition found.  When I look at the method with `pry`, the information I get is fairly unhelpful.  It shows that the method is in this module:

```
#<Module:0x007f9f84550200>#methods:
```

Just a memory location.  I assume that `rails` is creating the method for me, but how do I find what it is?  I don't even know what it is called when `rails` does this for you, so I can't figure out what to google.  What is going on and where can I find some documentation on how it works?

Comment: Are you using an auth gem/library? Also, just grepping/acking Ruby files in your gemset can be helpful, e.g., look for `current_user_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching for `def method_missing` and `define_method` invocations. Chances are that `current_user_has_ownership?` is defined dynamically or *intercepted* by a `method_missing` method.

This will be harder to search for if this code lives in an included gem.